# C++ implement my own static_assert

Tags: c++, c++11, templates, static-assert

As a learning project, I'm writing my own template metaprogramming static_assert. I found a metaprogramming trick online: try to create an array of size 0, which will fail to compile. So I'm using two nearly identical approaches: on Visual Studio, one works and the other doesn't, but I don't understand what's the difference. On g++ 5.4.0, neither works (not even with the "-std=c++14" flag). Why not?

```
//This correctly aborts the compile on Visual Studio 2015. 
//But on g++ it doesn't work (not even with the "-std=c++14" flag) .
template <bool b>
inline void my_static_assert_function()
{
    char member[b]; //if b is false, this is 0-length and fails to compile. 
}

//On Visual Studio 2015, this does give a warning, but does not
//abort the compile. Why not? It seems virtually identical to the
//previous one. And on g++, it doesn't even warn. 
template <bool b>
struct my_static_assert_struct
{
    char member[b]; //if b is false, this *warns* but compiles.
};

int main()
{
    my_static_assert_function<1 == 2>(); //This aborts the compile, great.
    my_static_assert_struct<1 == 2> c; //This does NOT abort the compile???
}
```

Question #1 -- why does "g++ -std=c++14 main.cpp" allow this to compile without even a warning? Shouldn't the my_static_assert_function work there? I'm using 5.4.0 for ubuntu.

Question #2 -- on Visual Studio 2015,  my_static_assert_function fails to compile, but  my_static_assert_struct compiles with a mere warning. But what's the difference? How can one work if the other doesn't?

Comment: GCC is a tricky beast. You really need to learn all its flags to turn it into an honest compiler.

Comment: (Which is why real programmers make arrays of size -1.)

Comment: @Kerrek SB: Until GCC finds a reason to make in an extension too.

Comment: `char member[b ? 1 : -1];`

Comment: The main two purposes of `static_assert` are: (1) Consistant working on all compilers anywhere it is allowed. (2) Useful error messages.

Answer (score 2):

As mentioned by @Kerrek SB in the comments, `gcc` uses some non-standard ISO C++ extension to allow for zero-sized arrays, although it gives you a warning. A far more elegant alternative is to [SFINAE](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/sfinae) out `false` via [`std::enable_if`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/enable_if), like so

```
#include <iostream>
#include <type_traits>

template<bool b, typename std::enable_if<b>::type* = nullptr>
void my_static_assert() 
{
    std::cout << "Assertion OK\n";
}

int main()
{
    my_static_assert < (1 < 2) > (); // ok
    //my_static_assert < (1 > 2) > (); // fails to compile
}
```

[<kbd>Live on Coliru</kbd>](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/3dd5942363aef760)

Another alternative (I think first proposed by [Andrei Alexandrescu](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Andrei_Alexandrescu)) is to leave a generic template non-defined, and define only the `true` specialization. Then, if you try to instantiate the `false` specialization, you'll get a compile-time error since you cannot instantiate an incomplete type. Example below:

```
template<bool> // generic
struct my_static_assert;

template<>
struct my_static_assert<true>{};

int main()
{
    my_static_assert < (1 < 2) >{}; // ok
    my_static_assert < (1 > 2) >{}; // fails to compile
}
```

[<kbd>Live on Coliru</kbd>](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/5dfdd3fb71d4dd12)

Answer (score 0):

Well, this doesn't use templates but I remember seeing this somewhere:

```c
#define __static_assert(con, id) static int assert_ ## id [2 * !!(con) - 1];
#define _static_assert(con, id) __static_assert(con, id) //expanding any macro that could be in `id` argument
#define static_assert(con) _static_assert(con, __COUNTER__)
```

Explanation:

- `!!(con)` makes any **non-zero** number **true (1)** and **zero** becomes **false (0)**
- by subtracting one you get **-1 when condition is not met** and **array can't have negative size** -> compile time error
- We don't want to have multiple arrays with same names, for that we use `__COUNTER__` macro to compose the name, but for that we need to expand it first

Comment: This is not a VLA, since the condition is supposed to be constexpr. On the other hand, zero-size arrays are illegal in standard C++. It would be better to set the array size to `1` if the condition is true.

Comment: Well, I tried it with gcc (well g++) and clang and it worked just fine, well I have an idea... But can you suggest a compiler for me that obeys standards better?

Comment: You don't need to change the compiler, just add the right flags: https://gcc.godbolt.org/z/seesTcacW

Comment: Thank you, I'm not really a flag expert, I also checked the argument should indeed be a constant expression...